# Easy to use Perl modules for neural networks

Tags: perl, module, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

In a project that I'm working on I have a decision problem and none of my attempts have given satisfying results: using domain specifik knowledge, trying to generate statistics and creating a statistical model etc etc.

I have basic knowledge about neural networks, now I want to try if that approach might yield some good results. I have a lot of data so all I want is basically to set up a simple NN, train it and see what I get.

Do you know about any decent **Perl** modules that might use for this purpose? I've found a few but I'd hate to waste my time trying all of them.

Comment: had you tried Rete's or just a complicated set of k-mean rules to solve your problem?

Comment: @mhambra: No sir, I have not. I will take it into consideration though. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several, but I'd start with `AI::NeuralNet::Simple`. On CPAN, the AI namespace has a whole bunch of others, some are wrappers for C libraries, others do fancy neural net things, but this is a simple base to start with. And it is well documented, which is not the case for some of the others

Caveats: none of the NN modules is that well maintained or widely tested. This one explicitly states that it is alpha code not for production use. For a proof-of-concept, it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks. That one seems nice and since you recommend it I will probably go for it, but I'll leave the question open a little bit longer just to see if I get any more suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use AI::FANN , you can find it on CPAN as well.